# Running a external program (pscp) from a Windows Service doesn't works

Tags: c++, windows-services, external-process

I'm writing a Windows Service in C++ (Visual Studio 2010) and this service must send a file to a remote server through secure copy (I'm using pscp.exe for that).

So, I'm using the `system` function to launch pscp.exe and when running as a normal application all works fine.

But if I try to run as a service, the service launch pscp.exe (I can see this on Task Manager), but the pscp.exe freezes and don't send anything to the remote host. And even if I stop the service, I need to kill the pscp process by myself.

I read in some forums to allow the service to "Interact with Desktop", but this doesn't resolved my problem.

I also tried to change the user account that the service log on as, with no results.

Any ideas?

It seems that is very difficult to run a external program from a Windows Service, even if this external program doesn't have any GUI, like pscp.exe.

Thanks!

-- 
Augusto Caringi

Comment: What account are you trying to use? Most services run as "**Local** System". Obviously that's not good enough for pscp if that has to connect to a remote host.

Answer (score 0):

What are your options on the `pscp` invocation?  If there is a 'silent' option, use that to avoid console interaction.  Often, this is `-q` or `/q`.

Be aware that any launched app will run in the same user account as your service. Does that account have permissions to do what you are asking of it?  Is the context (run directory, path) correct for `pscp` to do what you want?

Comment: The service can write the file in the specified directory with no problems. And I think that if the pscp program run with the same user account, it can read the file also.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use impersonate. Something like this...

```
    wchar_t* cmPath=readRegistryString(L"Software\\" TO_WCHAR(ORG_NAME) L"\\" TO_WCHAR(APP_NAME) L"\\" TO_WCHAR(APPLICATION_GROUP),TO_WCHAR(APPLICATION_EXEC_PATH));
if (!cmPath)
{
    return false;
}
HANDLE userToken=NULL;
DWORD sessId=WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId ();
if((long)sessId==-1)
{
    sessId=0;
}
WTSQueryUserToken (sessId, &userToken);
bool result=false;
if(userToken/**/ )
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    ZeroMemory(&sa,sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
    sa.nLength=sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    STARTUPINFOW si;
    ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
    si.cb=sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi,sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    CStringW str= L"\"";
    str=str+cmPath;
    str=str+L"\"";
    str.Replace(L"/",L"\\");

    if(CreateProcessAsUserW(userToken,NULL,str.GetBuffer(),NULL,NULL,false,NULL,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
    {
            result=true;
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        //nop;
    }
}
if(userToken)
    CloseHandle(userToken);
delete[] cmPath;
```

this piece of code i use to call GUI application from service, but i think it need not much changes for console app.

Answer (score 0):

You should launch your pscp application using the CreateProcess function rather than system. The latter relay your command to the command interpreter (cmd.exe), which might not be accessible from a service.

Comment: I'm doing some tests with _popen function instead of system, to capture the output of pscp. I find out that the program only freeze when it try to connect to the remote host. If I run pscp -v (to only show the version and exit) for example, it runs Ok.

Comment: jalf, I thought this. But I replaced pscp.exe by curl.exe (from libcurl) and this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem!

pscp.exe does not work running from a service. I don't know why.

But curl.exe (from libcurl) does and it support secure copy!

Thanks.